# Laravel Model/View Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, relationship

I am learning Laravel and just can't understand how to solve the below issue.

I have two tables (ofcourse not databases) :)

```
Table: Birds
id
name
species
....

Table: Eggs
id
egg_number
parent_id
....
```

Sample Data:

```
bird
id 1
name Jeff

egg
id 1
parent_id 1
```

I have two models which are Bird and Egg
I am simply displaying the data which is available in the database (MySQL).

eggs.blade.php

```
@foreach ($eggs as $egg)
..form data
{{ $egg->id }}
{{ $egg->parent_id }}
..end of form
@endforeach
```

This works all fine.  However I wish to show the name of the parent (bird) instead of the id. (so from the sample data it will show Jeff)

I have tried using this in the models

```
return $this->belongsTo('Bird'); //in Egg Model
return $this->belongsTo('Egg'); //in Bird Model
```

Would be really grateful for any help/explanation regarding this.

Comment: FYI you have two database tables, not two databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Egg` model you need to setup the relationship like so:

```
public function bird()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Bird::class,'parent_id');
}
```

If your column would have been `bird_id` it would have found the foreign key column on it's own however since it automatically tries the model name appended with `_id` it doesn't know which column to use. But you can directly specify the column that references the primary key of `Bird` with the second parameter in `belongsTo()`.

Once you do this you will simply be able to reference the relationship like so:

```
{{ $egg->bird->name }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, how would I display this in the view?.  I have tried $egg->bird.

Comment: Added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to relation it by doing bellow steps
1- In Bird Model you must to do like this

```
public function Eggs(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Egg');
}
```

2- Then in Egg Model

```
public function Bird(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Bird');
}
```

For more information visit [Laravel Documention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)

Hope will help you..

Comment: Thank you for the help as well.